# Edit <a href=""></a> value on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website, like href.li, and I would like to make a file, where webmasters can upload to their websites, and it will replace all `<a href="">`'s to my link.

**Example:**

**Old**:     `<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>`

**New**: `<a href="http://href.li/?http://www.google.com"> hrefli google</a>`

Is there any way of doing that on page load?

Comment: Of course there is. What have you tried? If it's urgent surely you've tried something.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, yet.

What do you mean by Fiddle please?

Comment: Are you trying to do it in php or javascript

Comment: That sounds a bit fishy to me, but at any rate, the only approaches I can think of are server-specific; that is, if a given webmaster is using Apache to serve their site, you could create an Apache module, and have them add it to Apache, that could rewrite links on each page as they load it.

Comment: I don't mind how. PHP would we better, but if not, javascript would be okay.

Comment: Just want to make sure I'm understanding what you're looking for: you want to supply some sort of code to various webmasters, and those webmasters will add that code to their sites, and when they do, all of the links on their sites will then be rewritten to point to your site.  Yes?

Comment: This sounds like something that could be used maliciously...

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for that JacobM, I'm going to be using it for forums, so they can have hidden referers.

Comment: Isn't it "always urgent"? - @JohnConde

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I'm doing it so webmasters can hide the referer from witch the traffic is coming from.

Comment: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not too clear, but this should update the href of links on page load.

Using JQuery:

```
<body onload="myFunction();">

function myFunction()
{
$("li a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all links on your page, and update the text too.
You will need jQuery for this to work.

```
$("a").each(function()
{
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var newhref = "http://href.li/?" + href;
    $(this).attr("href", newhref);

    var text = $(this).text();
    var newtext = "hrefLi " + text;
    $(this).text(newtext);
});
```

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf6Tc/)

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery :

```
$("a").each(function(){
  var orig = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', "http://href.li/?"+orig);
});
```

Comment: Why isn't this working user2829210?

http://puu.sh/52Ylg.png

Comment: And of course, it is better to use narrower selector such as `$("#websitedirectory a")` otherwise you will change all your links in the page

Comment: Is there any way of only changing outgoing links?
So I only change the links leaving that website?